# What is wrong with my very simple one page rails with Ajax?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Want to create a one page website, has an input text field, where user will enter a number then a submit button will output on the same page some string based on an algorithm I have written in Ruby.

I have created controller main_pages_controller.rb which has "home" as a method associated with "home.html.erb" view and a partial to display the output "_goclick.html.erb" . in the home page home.html.erb I have put this code:

```
Number: <input type="text" name="input_number">
<%= link_to "click here", {:action=>"go_convert"}, {:remote => true, :id=>"clk"} %>
<div id="allclick">
<%= render :partial => 'goclick' %>
</div>
```

In the controller I have included a method called go_convert where I embedded the ruby code for the conversion. and ended the method with these lines

```
respond_to do |format|
        format.js { render :layout=>false } 
end
```

I have also added a js file (go_convert.js.erb) under the same views folder with this code

```
$("#allclick").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => "goclick")) %>");
```

I have added the method go_convert as a post route to the routs configuration file
When I click the "click here" link am getting a js error

```
http://localhost:3000/main_pages/go_convert 404 (Not Found)
```

So I also added this route to my routes file

```
get "main_pages/go_convert"
```

Now when clicking the "click here" link, nothing is happening, not output, no page reload, no javascript errors.. 
what am I doing wrong?
Am using rails 3.2.12 and Ruby 1.9.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why did you use link_to and not a form? unless you handle it manually, i don't think "text_number" input field value got sent at all..

maybe that was the cause? so it render partial without any result which is the same as initial condition..

anyway try using form remote, something like this:

```
<%= form_tag url_for(action: "show"), remote: true do %>
  Number: <input type="text" name="input_number">
  <%= submit_tag "click here" %>
<% end %>
<div id="allclick">
  <%= render :partial => 'goclick' %>
</div>
```

also the "not found" error you got might be the result of link_to using GET request, by using form which use POST request by default you won't need to add GET routing at all

Answer (score 1):

You should create a javascript script which will be returned by your controller action like this:

in your controller action

```
def your_action
  @result = (your algorithm output)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js { render :action => "result" }
  end
end
```

in file result.js.erb

```
$('#allclick').empty().append('<%= escape_javascript( @result.to_s ) %>');
```

result.js script will be rendered as a response to the ajax request!

Comment: I missed to say in my question that I already have a respond_to block , please check edited question. but it is different than yours,(mine I copied and pasted from some internet resource). Anyway am using your block instead now. I already have a go_convert.js.erb file with the js code stated in my question, should I create another js file like the one you mentioned, or should I replace my existing one?

Comment: you can use yours i think code i wrote up there running without errors! in your controller action render :action => "go_convert" instead of "result" and you' re done =D

Answer (score 0):

Based in your routes, I think its a typo error, your **main_page_controllers.rb** should be **main_pages_controller.rb**

Comment: sorry this was a typo in the question, the file name is actually main_pages_controller.rb